How to use Perl to replace an entire line where a match is found?
I need to use Perl to replace an entire line if it has a match to a regular expression.
For example, if I have this file below:
Chicago no
Baltimore no
New York no

And I have a regex that returns matches for "Baltimore"
With a saved string containing "Baltimore yes"
How can I use perl to replace the line containing the match with my new line, Baltimore yes:
Chicago no
Baltimore yes
New York no


This replaces the entire line by including the rest of the line (.*) in the match, as requested:
perl -i -pe's/^Baltimore\b.*/Baltimore yes/' file

Alternate approach:
perl -i -ple'$_ = "Baltimore yes" if /^Baltimore\b/' file

This Keeps Baltimore or Baltimore  and replaces what follows:
perl -i -pe's/^Baltimore\b\K.*/ yes/' file

perl -i -pe's/^Baltimore\s\K.*/yes/' file


Use Perl's -i flag for in-place editing.
Use Perl's -pe flag to loop through the file line by line.
Use a regular expression to match and replace the line.
You can do:
perl -i -pe 's/^Baltimore no$/Baltimore yes/' filename.txt

If you want a more flexible solution that replaces any line containing "Baltimore" with "Baltimore yes", you can use:
perl -i -pe 's/^Baltimore.*$/Baltimore yes/' filename.txt

